# Update Commerce Data Templates with SPE

Tags: sitecore-commerce, powershell-extensions

How can I trigger Update Commerce Data Templates from SPE? I am automating a Docker deployment script and the one step that I am missing for it to be fully automated is being able to do this from powershell
Sitecore version is 9.2 if it matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore Commerce 9 uses custom .aspx page to generate data templates during installation process.

You can find this page here: **SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.*\SiteUtilityPages\GenerateCatalogTemplates.aspx**

The code of this page looks like below:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="log4net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Data.Engines" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Data.Proxies" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.SecurityModel" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Update" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Update.Installer" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Update.Installer.Exceptions" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Data.Managers" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Publishing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.Templates" %>

<%@ Language=C# %>
<HTML>
    <script runat="server" language="C#">
        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Catalog template generation started: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t") + "<br>");

            Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite("shell");
            using (new SecurityDisabler())
            {
                DateTime publishDate = DateTime.Now;
                Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
                var templateGenerator = new CatalogTemplateGenerator();
                templateGenerator.BuildCatalogTemplates(master);
            }

            Response.Write("Catalog template generation completed: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t") + "<br>");
        }

        protected String GetTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString("t");
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <form id="MyForm" runat="server">
            <div>Catalog templates generated.</div>
            Current server time is <% =GetTime()%>
        </form>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

This is what you can use OOTB.

In your case, you can invoke C# method from your PowerShell script, if you want.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks!